# Second DIV on all remaining space

Tags: html, css

I want to create two divs, one under other without JS and with IE8 support.

- Each has 100% width.
- Each with relative or absolute positioning for nested layout.
- Top div have height by content, not fixed (it is important) and bottom div on whole leftover space.

In my example bottom div is too short, how i can stretch it to bottom?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"><!--
* {
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 100%;
}

#super {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

#top {
    position: relative;
}

#bottom {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
--></style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="super">
<div id="top">top</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Flex can do this trivially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css table properties to create this layout.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="super">
  <div id="top">
    <div class="content">
      top
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="content">
      bottom
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#super {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#super > div {
  display: table-row;
}
#top {
  background: green;
}
#bottom {
  background: blue;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#super {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}

#top {
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1%;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
}

#bottom {
  background: blue;
}

#super > div {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<div id="super">
  <div id="top">
    <div class="content">
      top
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bottom">
    <div class="content">
      bottom</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table` for wrapping container and table-row for top and bottom divs:

```css
* {
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: solid 1px;
    width: 100%;
}
#super {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
}
#top {
    display: table-row;
    height: 1px;
    position: relative;
    background: orange;
}
#bottom {
    display: table-row;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="super">
<div id="top">top<br>top text</div>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `flex-box`

```css
.parent{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh
}
.child2{
  flex: 1;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"> first child</div>
  <div class="child2"> second child</div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xr4zmhqt/2/)** here

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#bottom {
position: relative;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
HEIGHT: 800px;
}
```